# Delay in getting value in tableView from Parse Query

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, parse-platform

I am trying to add comment function in my application using Parse as backend.

In that every time user start to chat with someone it has to go to Parse "Recent" - class and it has to check for the Arraylist match, if the row contains a match then it has to return a expected value and I will save that in a shared preference, else we create a value in the code itself and save it in preference.

Parse query is working fine and its passing the expected value,

#### but the problem is

sometime, it delays, not always. I checked the problem is from storing array that received value from parse. when I count array value, it shows like 1,1,3,4,5,5,7. 
The tableview doesn't display the value when user type it and tap upload comment button.  if user tap again because he doesn't see his comment, it will show two comments for him, because of asynchronous.

I want to use activity indicator(I only practice with webView), so that user can recognise that comment is uploading. but I don't know that which method I gotta use and which part I have to put the code for it.

#### My questions are

which way is the best using indicator for this problem,
and is there another way to solve this problem?

here is my code

```
class comment: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate {
@IBOutlet weak var tableViewComment: UITableView!
@IBOutlet weak var textFieldComment: UITextField!

var commentArray = [String]()
var parentObjectID = String()
var userIdArray = [String]()

@IBAction func uploadComment(sender: AnyObject) {
    var numberOfComment : Int = commentArray.count

    self.tableViewComment.reloadData()

    let comment = PFObject(className:"Comment")

    comment["createdBy"] = PFUser.currentUser()
    comment["comment"] = "" + textFieldComment.text
    comment["parent"] = parentObjectID
    comment["username"] = PFUser.currentUser()?.username

    comment.saveInBackground()




   // println("시작 :   \(commnetArray.count)")
    let numberOfCommentTwo = commentArray.count
    commentArray = []

    // println(" = \(numberOfComment), \(commentArray.count)")
    queryComment()



    if numberOfComment == numberOfCommentTwo {
        println("good")

    }else{

        println("bad = \(numberOfComment), \(commentArray.count)")
    }
    //인터넷이 느린지역 바로 업로드 되지 않는 문제
    //타이머를 넣어 해결 혹은 파스 서버와 대조 해보고 에러 메세지 줘야함
    //혹은 클릭 하면 어레이가 늘어나는걸 확인해야함 = 어레이 안의 벨류 숫자가 한번 클릭할때 하나 늘어나면 오케이




    self.tableViewComment.reloadData()
    textFieldComment.text = ""

}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    queryComment()

     }

func queryComment() {


    let queryComments = PFQuery(className: "Comment")

    queryComments.whereKey("parent", equalTo: "\(parentObjectID)")
    queryComments.orderByAscending("createdAt")
    queryComments.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (comments: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        // comments now contains the comments for myPost

        if error == nil {
            //에러없는 경우
            for post in comments! {
                self.commentArray.append(post["comment"] as! String)
                self.userIdArray.append(post["username"] as! String)


                self.tableViewComment.reloadData()
               // println("시작 :   \(self.commentArray)")

                //println("시작 :   \(self.numberOfComment)")

                self.tableViewComment.reloadData()
            }
            }else{
            println(error)
        }
    }
}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

return commentArray.count

}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell1", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell

    cell.textLabel?.text = self.commentArray[indexPath.row]
    cell.detailTextLabel!.text = "Id:" + self.userIdArray[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an activity indicator or progress HUD to prevent the user from uploading twice. You should also clear out the text field once the upload begins (similar to a text message) so the user can't push send again.

I'd highly recommend using [something like JGProgressHUD](https://github.com/JonasGessner/JGProgressHUD) which will make all of this a breeze for you. For example all you have to add to show the HUD is the following.

```
var progressHUD: JGProgressHUD = JGProgressHUD(style: JGProgressHUDStyle.ExtraLight)

// Show Progress HUD
progressHUD.position = JGProgressHUDPosition.Center
progressHUD.animation = JGProgressHUDFadeZoomAnimation()
progressHUD.showInView(self.view)
```

And then to remove it

```
// Dismiss progress HUD
self.progressHUD.dismissAnimated(true)
```

Show the HUD at the beginning of `@IBAction func uploadComment`. Also change `comment.saveInBackground()` to use `comment.saveInBackgroundWithBlock` and dismiss the HUD in the completion block of the save.

Comment: This is not the answer I expected, but it is a good information.